# Rotating lego nxt based on an angle

Tags: python, lego-mindstorms, nxt

I would like to knows is there a way to rotate the lego nxt using an angle based on two points r(x1,y1) and p(x2,y2) without causing any miscalculation when the robot changes from facing north to south,east or west. Thanks

Regards,
Edward

Comment: Exactly how are the two points used for rotation? Is the robot position a third point (origin)?

Comment: @Jake using tangent to calculate the angle between the two points and the using the angle based on some calculations to rotate the robot to the object

Comment: You can't get an angle from only two points, you need to describe this moer thoroughly.